# Convert Quantization Colors in Float format to RGB Integer

Tags: python, colors

What I'm doing is reducing colors in an image by quantization, but instead of using floats I need to translate into RGB (eg. array(255, 255, 255)). I've found similar questions but not a straightforward/direct solution.

Returning `clustered` produces the array of floats. **How do you convert the float to the RGB equivalent?**

```
 # Pixel Matrix
pixel = reshape(img,(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1],3))

# Clustering
centroids,_ = kmeans(pixel,8) # six colors will be found

# Quantization
qnt,_ = vq(pixel,centroids)

# Shape Quantization Result
centers_idx = reshape(qnt,(img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
clustered = centroids[centers_idx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert any array of floats to array of bytes (8-bit unsigned integers, from 0 to 255), you have some options. The one I prefer for more general conversions is this:

```
bytearray = (floatarray*255).astype('uint8')
```

This should work if you have any array of positive floats whose pixel values for each channel vary between 0.0 and 1.0. If you have arbitrary positive values, you could do `floatarray /= floatarray.max()` first, to normalize the values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not to mention that Scipy, PIL and Matplotlib have a lot of smarty functions with options that already return images, or image-preformated arrays (rgb, or rgba).